# How do I use mod_wsgi.so to run python as an apache module?

Tags: python, apache

How do I set it up with an easy to explain solution,

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide

gives a very technical answer which I can not understand.

Comment: ... It's a technical thing to do. What were you expecting?

Comment: There is a list at the bottom of the link you provided to setup instructions for some python web frameworks. Why not check out those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try and write WSGI apps from scratch. Use a framework - Django, Flask, Pyramid, etc.

Comment: Thank you I am learning Django for starters, similar to cakePHP and YII thanks. You saved me months of trouble!